# How to extract date and time text from HTML using bs4 python?

Tags: python, html, datetime, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using python bs4 to extract the date and time from these HTML code

**[ < time class="published-date relative-date" data-published-date="2020-07-21T18:49:14Z" datetime="2020-07-21T18:49:14Z" > < /time >,
< time class="published-date relative-date" data-published-date="2020-07-21T18:48:26Z" datetime="2020-07-21T18:48:26Z" >< / time>,
< time class="published-date relative-date" data-published-date="2020-07-21T18:47:00Z" datetime="2020-07-21T18:47:00Z"></ time>,
< time class="published-date relative-date" data-published-date="2020-07-21T18:43:21Z" datetime="2020-07-21T18:43:21Z"> </ time>]**

**

and was wondering how I can get rid of the other text aside from the date and time? For example, **'2020-07-21T18:49:14Z'** and have it displayed as **'2020-07-21', '18:49:14Z'**

Here is my code so far:

**date_and_time=soup.find_all('time', attrs={'class':'published-date relative-date'})**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
soup.find(id=<ID OF TIME>)
```

Then you will only get the time. If you are using find_all, you will get all text that matches the attributes.

You can also just split the text you have right now:

```
date_and_time = '2020-07-21T18:49:14Z'
print(date_and_time.split('T')

['2020-07-21', '18:49:14Z']
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will create pandas dataframe with `time` and `date` columns:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_string = '''
    <time class="published-date relative-date" data-published-date="2020-07-21T18:49:14Z" datetime="2020-07-21T18:49:14Z"></time>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for t in soup.select('time.published-date.relative-date'):
    all_data.append(t.get('data-published-date'))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])

df['date'] = df[0].dt.date
df['time'] = df[0].dt.time

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                          0        date      time
0 2020-07-21 18:49:14+00:00  2020-07-21  18:49:14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dateutil` to parse the raw date-time string. Install dateutil using pip using the command `pip install python-dateutil`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil import parser

text = '<time class="published-date relative-date" date-published-date="2020-07-21T18:49:14Z" datetime="2020-07-21T18:49:14Z">'

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
for t in soup.find_all('time', attrs={'class':'published-date relative-date'}):
    date_time_str = t.get('datetime')
    date_time = parser.parse(date_time_str)
    print (date_time.date())
    print (date_time.time())
```

**Outputs:**

```
2020-07-21
18:49:14
```